# Opening Visual Studio Code command palette by Ctrl + P and Ctrl Shift + P

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

The shortcut for opening the Visual Studio Code command palette in Windows is Ctrl + Shift + P as in the screenshot.

[image: VS Code Command palette]

But I occasionally found out that Ctrl + P also opens the command palette. What is the difference between these two shortcut keys?

Answer (score 1):

The command palette in VSCode is dual-purpose; it offers you a list of open files initially, and only offers commands once `>` is entered. So Ctrl-P opens the palette with no input (starting with a file list) while Ctrl-Shift-P opens it with a ">" pre-filled (starting with a command list). There is no other difference.